# change body color using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

hi2all i write code which change the color of webpage when the user click the div

but doesn't work here is my code what's wrong with it

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="gencyolcu" />

    <title>Untitled 1</title>


    <script type="text/javascript">


    var x=document.getElementById("m");
    x.addEventListener("click",function{


      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });

    </script>
</head>

<body >

<div id="m">kfjgflg</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @Bergi It's not a exact duplicate as this code has other bug that can disallow the code to work correctly. See my answer to see it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16213958/241942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
        <meta name="author" content="gencyolcu" />
        <title>Untitled 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="m">kfjgflg</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var x=document.getElementById("m");
            x.addEventListener("click",function(){
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Because you have two problems in your original code:

- Is missing a **important** () after the token "function".
- The Javascript only recognizes a element after the page or element has ready. In this case, the element only is read to be recognized if your code has after the Javascript Codes that recognizes it.

The code above fixes this.

A important observation: In some IE's, this code can not work, because of the use of x.addEventListener, in this case, you can transform the anonymous function in a normal function (with a name) and listen with *addEventListener* (if available) and *onclick* (recommended for old IE's).

In this way,the code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
        <meta name="author" content="gencyolcu" />
        <title>Untitled 1</title>            
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="m">kfjgflg</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeColor(){
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            var x=document.getElementById("m");
            if(!!x.addEventListener){ //If exists
                x.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
            }
            x.onclick = changeColor; //It's a property, and ALWAYS can be set (but in some cases is not recognized)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a working  example with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/fjorgemota/qCXH3/

Answer (score 0):

If you had opened your JavaScript error console it would have told you that you cannot access the property/method `addEventListener` of `undefined`.

You need to look for the element `m` *after* the DOM tree has been built. Either place into a function which gets called on `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    /* ... */
}, false);
```

or place your script at the end of your `<body>`.

Comment: thanks dear i also figured out that i missed the () after the function in this line  
x.addEventListener("click",function{

Comment: @TheSniper104: Have a look at the other answer. It seems like Fernando's answer is more fitting and actually addresses both problems.